# OpenGL unit vs natural measuring

Tags: opengl

Is there any algorithm/formula that  can help me to figure out  natural dimensions of a drawn object on OpenGL scene by using orthogonal projection. ? 
For examle: 3 Units = 3milimeters.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the operating system for its copy of your monitor's [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) information.  That should contain the display width and height in centimeters.

Answer (score 3):

The units can be anything and different people will have a different design approach. Some will definitely use metric while others use imperial units, and on top of that there will be many arbitrary ones. You just have to guess from each application separately, what they might be using.

Comment: Agree, but my question is about my application, so I was asking actually about the way to figure out from the code a relationship between opengl unit and natural dimension.

Comment: Then you can choose any unit you like. I suggest centimeters. Or if you have, say, real-world data loaded without any scaling, then you look at the bounding box of that data and what the real equivalent would measure. But the best approach is to first choose your units and then scale everything to match.